# Is an anchor with an insecure URL vulnerable to XSS?

Tags: javascript, url, xss

Let's say that there is an `<a>` element hyperlink in a website. I can control what the link is, except for the protocol, which is http. I know that I could type `javascript:doWhatever()`, but it doesn't work in this case because the protocol is already set as http, and I can't change it to `javascript:`. So is an XSS injection still possible in this case?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you insert a `"` to close the `href` part

Comment: That's incorrect for HTML, it should be `&quot`, so I think you can =)

Comment: That's what I meant sorry!

Comment: Sharing the exact escaping mechanism is helpful. If you don't know you could go over some of these:

Comment: If every other possible XSS vector is sealed, and you truly have made it impossible to change the protocol (which is *very* unlikely), then you have not opened any new known XSS vectors. But leaving security to random people on the internet is possibly the least secure risk mitigation strategy there is...

Comment: https://portswigger.net/web-security/cross-site-scripting/cheat-sheet

Comment: I don't think `<a>` can load unsafe things on the current page, unless the link is clicked and the browser navigates to the site and the site it goes to is vulnerable to XSS. I don't know for sure though.